# What is causing this error ERROR: undefined method `mysql_service' for #<Chef::Recipe:0x00000003ca0870>?

Tags: centos, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

Basically I want to create a cookbook that installs MySQL 5.6 so I though I would utilize mysql from the supermarket.

I started off by creating a fresh cookbook using `chef generate cookbook MYSQL` Then added `depends 'mysql', '~> 8.0'` and run a `berks install` which runs successfully and installs the mysql cookbook.

Here is my default.rb

```
mysql_service 'default' do
 version '5.7'
 bind_address '0.0.0.0'
 port '3306'
 data_dir '/data'
 initial_root_password 'vagrant'
 action [:create, :start]
end
```

I run this command to run the cookbook - `sudo chef-client --local recipes/default.rb` which gives me the following output

```
[2017-08-23T18:54:31+00:00] INFO: Started chef-zero at chefzero://localhost:1 with repository at /home/vagrant
One version per cookbook
[2017-08-23T18:54:31+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
Starting Chef Client, version 13.2.20
[2017-08-23T18:54:31+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 13.2.20 ***
[2017-08-23T18:54:31+00:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux
[2017-08-23T18:54:31+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 26421
[2017-08-23T18:54:31+00:00] INFO: The plugin path /etc/chef/ohai/plugins does not exist. Skipping...
[2017-08-23T18:54:33+00:00] INFO: Run List is []
[2017-08-23T18:54:33+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to []
[2017-08-23T18:54:33+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for ardent-admin
[2017-08-23T18:54:33+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2017-08-23T18:54:33+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
resolving cookbooks for run list: []
[2017-08-23T18:54:33+00:00] INFO: Loading cookbooks []
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...

Running handlers:
[2017-08-23T18:54:33+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2017-08-23T18:54:33+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 02 seconds
[2017-08-23T18:54:33+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to 
/home/vagrant/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-08-23T18:54:33+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the 
stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-08-23T18:54:33+00:00] ERROR: undefined method `mysql_service' for #<Chef::Recipe:0x00000004e58a68>
[2017-08-23T18:54:33+00:00] FATAL: 
Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited 
unsuccessfully (exit code 1)



[2017-08-24T13:04:11+00:00] WARN: 
*****************************************
[2017-08-24T13:04:11+00:00] WARN: Did not find config file: 
/etc/chef/solo.rb, using command line options.
[2017-08-24T13:04:11+00:00] WARN: 
*****************************************
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:37:in `initialize': 
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - recipes[MYSQL::default] 
(Errno::ENOENT)
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:37:in `open'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:37:in `open'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.2.20/lib/chef/application/client.rb:532:in `block in fetch_recipe_tarball'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.2.20/lib/chef/application/client.rb:531:in `open'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.2.20/lib/chef/application/client.rb:531:in `fetch_recipe_tarball'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.2.20/lib/chef/application/client.rb:346:in `reconfigure'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.2.20/lib/chef/application.rb:57:in `run'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.2.20/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:225:in `run'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.2.20/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/chef-solo:263:in `load'
from /usr/bin/chef-solo:263:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a single recipe like that doesn't process dependencies at all. It's generally not recommended for anything other than the very first Chef tutorial. You want something like `chef-solo -r 'recipe[mycookbook::default]`.

Comment: I run the command - sudo chef-solo --recipe-url recipes[MYSQL::default] and get a new error, editing above to show it.

Comment: As the name implies, that command line option takes a URL, which is not what you are giving. `-r` is for passing in a run list and is what you want to use, though that specific run list is probably wrong. You need to use the name of your cookbook, not `mysql`. Using chef-solo is a relatively advanced mode, not something you should use as a beginner, stick to normal `chef-client` and Chef Server if you are new.